# File still used by a processus after closing a streamwriter

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio

Recently i'm on file manipulation. 
So i created a "sub" who open a file read it and close it at first hand. And in a second hand i reopen it and rewrite it. But there is my problem, when i do it visual studio tell me that the file is already use by a processus.

there is my code if you find something, let me know:

```
Function OpenTxt(ByVal Path As String) As String()

    'Variables
    Dim mStreamReader As StreamReader

    Dim Line As String
    Dim J As Integer
    Dim K As Integer
    Dim mStock() As String
    Dim TempTbl() As String
    Dim mSplit() As String


    'Ini
    If Not File.Exists(Path) Then

    End If
    mStreamReader = New StreamReader(Path, True)
    J = -1
    K = -1

    'Début
    Do
        Line = mStreamReader.ReadLine
        If Line <> "" Then
            mSplit = Split(Line, "||",, vbTextCompare)
            K = K + 1
            ReDim Preserve TempTbl(K)
            TempTbl(K) = Line

            Select Case mSplit(0)
                Case "IsOpen"
                    If mSplit(1) <> mEApp.LicenseKey Then

                    ElseIf mSplit(1) = 0 Then
                        TempTbl(K) = mSplit(0) & "||" & mEApp.LicenseKey
                    End If
                Case "STOCK"
                    J = J + 1
                    ReDim Preserve mStock(J)
                    mStock(J) = mSplit(1)
            End Select

        End If
    Loop Until Line Is Nothing

    mStreamReader.Close()
    mStreamReader = Nothing

    Dim mStreamWriter As StreamWriter
    mStreamWriter = New StreamWriter(Path, True)

    For K = 0 To UBound(TempTbl)
        mStreamWriter.WriteLine(TempTbl(K))
    Next

    mStreamWriter.Close()
    mStreamWriter = Nothing

    OpenTxt = mStock

    Return OpenTxt

End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the `Using` clause

```
Using mStreamReader As New StreamReader(Path, True)

    ' write your code here

End Using
```

Learn more about `Using` in this [Article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx)

Your code will be like this:

```
Function OpenTxt(ByVal Path As String) As String()



    Dim Line As String
    Dim J As Integer
    Dim K As Integer
    Dim mStock() As String
    Dim TempTbl() As String
    Dim mSplit() As String

    'Ini
    If Not File.Exists(Path) Then

    End If
    Using mStreamReader As New StreamReader(Path, True)
        J = -1
        K = -1

        'Début
        Do
            Line = mStreamReader.ReadLine
            If Line <> "" Then
                mSplit = Split(Line, "||", , vbTextCompare)
                K = K + 1
                ReDim Preserve TempTbl(K)
                TempTbl(K) = Line

                Select Case mSplit(0)
                    Case "IsOpen"
                        If mSplit(1) <> mEApp.LicenseKey Then

                        ElseIf mSplit(1) = 0 Then
                            TempTbl(K) = mSplit(0) & "||" & mEApp.LicenseKey
                        End If
                    Case "STOCK"
                        J = J + 1
                        ReDim Preserve mStock(J)
                        mStock(J) = mSplit(1)
                End Select

            End If
        Loop Until Line Is Nothing

        mStreamReader.Close()

    End Using

    Using mStreamWriter As New StreamWriter(Path, True)

        For K = 0 To UBound(TempTbl)
            mStreamWriter.WriteLine(TempTbl(K))
        Next

        mStreamWriter.Close()

    End Using

    OpenTxt = mStock

    Return OpenTxt

End Function
```

Comment: You don't *have* to use `using`, although there's usually no good reason not to do so. The OP was `Close`ing the reader which should achieve the same result.

Comment: When using object that inherits IDisposable it is recommended to use `Using` statments. And in this example the OP is using the same StreamWriter multiple time with different Files. So it is best practice to Use `USING` statment.

Comment: I don't disagree that it's usually a good idea to use it, and may be a good idea here. What I disagree with is the second word in your answer. You don't **have** to use it, and in this case (where the OP is calling `Close`, which performs exactly the same cleanup as `Dispose` on a [`StreamReader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.close(v=vs.110).aspx)), it should have no material impact.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever it doesn't do the same thing in the event of an exception. I agree you don't have to use `using`, but you probably should.

Comment: I did what you advice me, but it's remain the same. 
For more info I use the same file in both streamreader and streamwriter.
The fact is i don't know why after closing the file i can't reopen it with another time of stream function.
It's most like the processus of opening for reading it's still not closed after the instruction of closing.

Comment: You need to remove "Dim mStreamReader As StreamReader" if you want to use using statement. I test your code and it works fine with me.

Comment: I forget to explain one thing, this function is write inside a class library (eg: addin for excel) 
And i write it inside a basic windows form application and it works so maybe it's another thing

Answer (score 0):

You could also read all lines using

[System.IO.File.ReadAllLines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1(v=vs.110).aspx)

[System.IO.File.WriteAllLines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writealllines(v=vs.110).aspx)

Then you can just do it as follows:

```
Function OpenTxt(ByVal Path As String) As String()

    'Variables
    Dim Line As String
    Dim J As Integer
    Dim K As Integer
    Dim mStock() As String
    Dim TempTbl() As String
    Dim mSplit() As String

    Dim Lines as String() = IO.File.ReadAllLines(Path)
    J = -1
    K = -1

    'Début
    For Each Line in Lines
        If Line <> "" Then
            mSplit = Split(Line, "||",, vbTextCompare)
            K = K + 1
            ReDim Preserve TempTbl(K)
            TempTbl(K) = Line

            Select Case mSplit(0)
                Case "IsOpen"
                    If mSplit(1) <> mEApp.LicenseKey Then

                    ElseIf mSplit(1) = 0 Then
                        TempTbl(K) = mSplit(0) & "||" & mEApp.LicenseKey
                    End If
                Case "STOCK"
                    J = J + 1
                    ReDim Preserve mStock(J)
                    mStock(J) = mSplit(1)
            End Select

        End If
    Next

    IO.File.WriteAllLines(Path,TempTbl)

    OpenTxt = mStock

    Return OpenTxt

End Function
```

No need for Streams. All depends on the scope of the files. Bigger files -> more memory needed.

If problem stays, the file is probably open somewhere else.

Comment: You also might consider List(of String) instead the Array, since you wouldn't need it to ReDim

Comment: hi thanks, for the tip i will try it tomorrow and let you know if the problem is solved

Comment: sorry for the long delay but the result is still the same...
It's impossible to rewrite the file. I don't understand why it dosn't work in a class library but it's ok in a windows form application...

Comment: do you know which process uses the file? If you're not sure, you can use ProcessExplorer from SysInternals to lookup this file handle and track this process down.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the long absence of answering.
I'm back on this project and I find my answer. There was a streamwriter before this procedure who was open and wasn't closed. So for now it works well.

Best Regard to everyone